# Csv reading with fs and events, problem in manipulating the data for the scope of the function. With nodejs and jest

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, jestjs

I need help with one thing:

I have a function that generates an array of objects, as follows:

```
const parse = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');

async function dadosCsv(arquivo){
  let csvData = []
  fs.createReadStream(arquivo)
  .pipe(
    parse({
        columns: true,
    })
  )
  .on('data', async(row) =>{
    csvData.push(row)
  })
  .on('end', async() =>{
    return csvData
  })
}

module.exports = dadosCsv;
```

Then I try to use this array in a separate test file using jest methods

```
const dadosCsv = require('../helper/dadosCsv')
// Log function
console.log(dadosCsv);

describe("Testando", () => {
    dadosCsv(__dirname + '/importar_notas_sp.csv')

    test('Cenario', async() =>{
        csvData.forEach(function(item) {
          // Trying to log data from within the array into the above function
          console.log(JSON.parse(item.msgRetorno))
        })
    })
})
```

Error obtained, obs: I can get the asynchronous function of the other file, but I can't use the array from within it:

Trying to log data from within the array into the above function
        ReferenceError: csvData is not defined

```
      21 |     
      22 |     test('Cenario', async() =>{
    > 23 |         csvData.forEach(function(item) {
         |         ^
      24 |           console.log(JSON.parse(item.msgRetorno))
      25 |         })
      26 |     }) 

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/importar_notas_SP.test.js:23:9)
```

Log function:

```
  console.log src/importar_notas_SP.test.js:20
    [AsyncFunction: dadosCsv]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wesley, it looks like you are a beginner in Nodejs, Nevermind but you are missing a few things in code. I am modifying the code a bit.I would also suggest you learn more about `promises` and `async-await`. You have to handle call  to `dadosCsv(__dirname + '/importar_notas_sp.csv')` function correctly and also you need to return promise from function `dadosCsv`

```
const parse = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');

function dadosCsv(arquivo) {
    let csvData = []
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.createReadStream(arquivo)
            .pipe(
                parse({
                    columns: true,
                })
            )
            .on('data', async (row) => {
                csvData.push(row)
            })
            .on('end', async () => {
                resolve(csvData)
            })
            .on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err)
            })
    })
}
module.exports = dadosCsv;
```

======================test file=======================

```
const dadosCsv = require('../helper/dadosCsv')
describe("Testando", () => {

    test('Cenario', async () => {
        let csvData = await dadosCsv(__dirname + '/importar_notas_sp.csv')
        csvData.forEach(function(item) {
            // Trying to log data from within the array into the above function
            console.log(JSON.parse(item.msgRetorno))
        })
    })
})
```

I have created repl for you try  playing around it and find out more about `promise` and `async-await`
https://repl.it/repls/LovingUprightMp3

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me to understand better async functions I'm really a beginner yet! But I have a lot of desire and I will go a long way!